# How do I store and retrieve a colon (:) in a MySQL field?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I'm simply trying to store a URI in a MySQL table.  When I retrieve it the ":" disappears. So http://www.example.com becomes http//www.example.com  I've researched it and there are solutions for ; (semicolons), , (commas), quote marks et etc., but not for colons.

I've tried http \ ://www.xyz.com (no spaces) but that converts it http/://www.example.com  I'm using php.  Any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); //security parameters not shown

$sql = "SELECT * FROM uri WHERE myURI='" . $id . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ($row) {
        $SendTo = $row["SendTo"];
        header("Location: " . $SendTo);
    }
}
?>
```

Note:  I am not showing insertion code because at this stage I am simply entering the URI manually to create a POC.

Comment: are you simply storing URI into db column? if yes then validate URL in PHP and directly store URL into column which has field type `varchar` or `text`, do no escape it , just validate it in php and store it directly. doing above will give you a extra check for URL if url is invalid throw an error back or save it normally

Comment: I'm validating the URI when I store it.  That's not the problem - it's when I retrieve the URI that I lose the colon.

Comment: you must be saving with `addslashes()` function. remove it.

Comment: We'd love to see some code please.

Comment: I'm not using addslashes @Norman

Comment: I see that the link that I gave as duplicate is not the link that I meant to give. Please read & act on [mcve]. This includes that we can cut & paste (including setting up the db state) & get your behaviour. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/3404097 It seems likely your state is not what you think. PS You are jumping to conclusions about what I read or assumed.

Comment: You can cut and paste my code and use it as is.  The URI is saved in a varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mysqli_real_escape_string()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp) function to escape slashes and store safely in database

For e.g.

```
$url  = "http://www.example.com";
$safeURL = mysqli_real_escape_string($url);
```

and then use `$safeURL` var in SQL to store.

Comment: My problem is with colons not slashes.  I have tried this solution and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Chiwda all the symbol will be escaped with slash and you will get as you expect using this function. Have you tested it ?

Comment: Please never recommend `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  If a developer is still using `mysql_` functions then it is time to upgrade to `mysqli_`.  If they need escaping or are handling user-supplied / insecure data then prepared statements with placeholders is the way.

Comment: @MehulV. Came back to this problem and it worked this time using your solution. I had another bug that prevented it from working. I have accepted and upvoted.